# Why does the solution set for this inequality turn out this way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

$$x^2-6x-7\ge 0$$

Steps I took:

$$(x-7)(x+1)\ge 0$$

$$x-7\ge 0\quad x+1\ge0$$

$$x\ge 7\quad x\ge -1$$

When I test the solution set, I realize that it must be $x\ge 7\quad or\quad x\le -1$

What is going on here?

Comment: Hint: If $ab \gt 0$ then $a \gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$ OR $a \lt 0$ and $b \lt 0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up until this point

$$(x-7)(x+1)\ge 0$$

your reasoning to correct.

But now look at the expression. It is a product of two numbers. Ask yourself: When is a product of two real numbers positive? The product is only positive, if both terms have same sign. Hence,

A)Both expressions have positive sign: $x-7\geq 0$ and $x+1\geq0$

or B)Both expressions have negative sign: $x-7\leq 0$ and $x+1\leq0$.

Now, look at: A) $x\geq7$ and $x\geq-1$. Both conditions are only satisfied if $x\geq7$

Now try to the same for B).

Comment: So I need to test both cases and see which solution satisfies both conditions in case A and then case B?

Comment: So for example: 

$4x^{ 2 }-14x+12\ge 0\Rightarrow (4x-6)(x-2)\ge0$

Case A: $4x-6\ge 0\quad and\quad x-2\ge 0$

Case B: $4x-6\le 0\quad and\quad x-2\le 0$


So, $x\ge 2$ satisfies Case A and $x\le 1.5$ satisfies Case B

Thus, $x\ge 2\quad or\quad x\le 1.5$

Comment: Yes, Excellent :)!

Answer (score 3):

What one should do in general when solving one-variable inequalities is:

- Solve the equality, i.e. replace the inequality sign with an equality sign.
- Graph the function, marking the points where we have equality.
- Now you can write down the interval where the inequality holds.

Comment: Ahem try this with a 5-variable inequality ;-) While this works on the "maternity school level", anywhere higher up you shall go the rigorous way. This answer is not quite general, it works only for 1-variable inequalities with continuous functions.

Comment: @yo' While this answer's claim to generality is indeed overstated, I think your critique is a bit harsh! If the OP had asked how to solve the equation $x^2-6x-7=0$ and an answer responded "in general we can solve quadratics by factorisation, completing the square, or the quadratic formula" it would be accurate to respond "but the OP's problem is actually just a special case of a quintic equation in seven variables, where most of the coefficients are zero - try completing the square or the quadratic formula on that!" But it would still have been a useful answer to the OP.

Comment: I like this answer (+1) because *graph-sketching is an important skill in pre-calc level maths*. If you are solving $f(x)\geq0$ it is a good idea to understand how the function $f$ behaves, particularly if there is a contextual meaning behind it (e.g. you're trying to see where the profit function is positive in an economics problem). My main criticism is that while it gives an alternative method, this answer does not highlight or address the flaw in the OP's reasoning (the false claim that $AB\geq0 \implies A\geq0$ or $B\geq0$).

Comment: I am all for your approach. In addition, I just want to add in some detail. The original inequality is now broken in two lines, namely (1) $y = (x – 7)(x + 1)$, the quadratic curve; and (2) $Y = o$, the $x$-axis. The question is now boiled down to find what range of $x$ that satisfies the inequality $y \ge Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB\ge 0$, you cannot conclude that $A\ge 0$ or $B\ge 0$. What you should be doing is something similar but different.

The function $f(x) = x^2-6x-7$ is what is called "continuous", which means that if it changes sign from $x=a$ to $x=b$, then there is a value $x=c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=0$. You should be looking for where the function is zero (namely at $-1$ and 7), and then testing whether $f(x)$ is positive or negative at other values.

For instance, $f(0)=-7$, so $f(x)$ is negative for all $x$ between $-1$ and 7. $f(8)=9\ge0$, so $f(x)$ is positive for all $x$ greater than 7, etc.